# Pandas: No columns to parse from file

Tags: python, pandas

Good afternoon

I have looked through several of the solutions linked to this problem and nothing has been able to help me. I do not understand if it is an error with the actual csv file or an error within the code itself. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import islice
import csv
from cStringIO import StringIO

sio = StringIO()
def forex_file():
    with open("USD-ZAR.csv", "r+") as exchange_file:
        for row in islice(csv.reader(exchange_file), 3, 256, None):
            sio.write(row)

sio.seek(0)
df1 = pd.read_csv(sio, sep=",", encoding="utf-8", delim_whitespace=True)
```

I purposely placed the "delim_whitespace=True" part within the code as this has been the common suggestion in many of the other posts but is has done nothing in this case as my csv file is split by normal commas and not by white space or tabs.

Any help will really be appreciated!

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the first few rows of your actual csv

Comment: You're not sharing what the actual error or problem is

Comment: Have you tried calling `forex_file()` so it attempts to populate something in `sio` (it's not present in your posted code if so...)? Looks like you'll find that `sio.getvalue()` is going to return an empty string - hence the error you're getting.

Comment: Is there a reason `read_csv()` won't open the file natively? What does the csv look like?

Comment: Here is a direct link to the site I download the information fro (select the Rand per USD option). If you download it, you will see that the first 2 rows are useless info while the 3rd row is blank. Then the information starts and continues up until row 256 after which a blank row is placed and the info is repeated yet again worthlessly. Hence my intention of slicing the data between rows 3 and 256 within the code.https://www.resbank.co.za/Research/Rates/Pages/SelectedHistoricalExchangeAndInterestRates.aspx

Comment: So I removed the entire first part of the code and only used the code df1 = pd.read_csv("USD-ZAR.csv", sep=",", encoding="utf-8", delim_whitespace=True).... still received the same error.